# Groupby using GORM or MySql

Tags: mysql, grails, group-by, grails-orm

My table has three column

```
created(Date)
score(int)(value is between 1-3)
id(long)
```

currently I am using Grails(GORM)

```
 def listData= DaSes.createCriteria().list([max: 5, order: 'desc', sort: 'created']) { 
            projections {
                groupProperty('created')
                count('id')
            }
        }

[[date,count(of all scores)],[date,count(of all scores),...]
```

But I want result like this

```
[[date,count(of all scores),count(score1 for current day),count(score2 current day),count(score3 current day)],....]
```

Please guide me in this .

Answer (score 3):

This is logically not possible.If you are using Group by on multiple columns then it gives [image: GROUPBY MULTIPLE COLUMN OUTCOME]

And this result is correct.

Comment: link-only answers are strongly discouraged.

Comment: Soory But I want to mentioned that I have tried this thing in GORM and MY Sql both.And Finally I got this is logically not possible.

Comment: @C_B if you have an better answer Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.